# ERC20 Crowdsale Contract Deployed - but Fails to Sell Tokens

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, erc-20

I successfully deployed both an `ERC20` Token as well as a `Crowdsale` Contract to the `Ropsten` Testnet.

-I used code from `OpenZeppelin`'s library for both contracts

-While the deployments work and I'm able to interact with both contracts through `truffle console`, the problem is that when I try to buy Tokens from my Crowdsale contract by sending `ETH` to it, the Transactions fail repeatedly - and I have no idea why.

Here's the code to my `ERC20` Token, which I'm calling `POPCoin`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";


contract POPCoin is ERC20 {

  string public constant name = "POPCoin";
  string public constant symbol = "POPC";
  uint8 public constant decimals = 3;
  uint256 public actualNumber = 0;

  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 1000000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

  /**
   * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
   */
  constructor() public {
    _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
    actualNumber = INITIAL_SUPPLY / (10 ** uint256(decimals));
  }

}
```

Here's the code to the Crowdsale Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "./POPCoin.sol";


contract PopCoinCrowdsale is Crowdsale {

    constructor(uint256 rate, address wallet, IERC20 token) 
        Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) public {

        }        
}
```

As you can see, this second contract inherits from `OpenZeppelin`'s `Crowdsale.sol` contract, which is your basic standard Crowdsale contract (I'm including the code for that below.)

It has a "fallback" type function that simply calls the `buyTokens()` function, so basically if you just send `ETH` to this contract, this fallback function will immediately catch that `ETH` and trigger the aforementioned `buyTokens()` function.

But like I said, this fails - and I get errors like this:

[image]

Here's that `Crowdsale` Contract from `OpenZeppelin`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "../math/SafeMath.sol";
import "../token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
import "../utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

/**
 * @title Crowdsale
 * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale,
 * allowing investors to purchase tokens with ether. This contract implements
 * such functionality in its most fundamental form and can be extended to provide additional
 * functionality and/or custom behavior.
 * The external interface represents the basic interface for purchasing tokens, and conform
 * the base architecture for crowdsales. They are *not* intended to be modified / overridden.
 * The internal interface conforms the extensible and modifiable surface of crowdsales. Override
 * the methods to add functionality. Consider using 'super' where appropriate to concatenate
 * behavior.
 */
contract Crowdsale is ReentrancyGuard {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

  // The token being sold
  IERC20 private _token;

  // Address where funds are collected
  address private _wallet;

  // How many token units a buyer gets per wei.
  // The rate is the conversion between wei and the smallest and indivisible token unit.
  // So, if you are using a rate of 1 with a ERC20Detailed token with 3 decimals called TOK
  // 1 wei will give you 1 unit, or 0.001 TOK.
  uint256 private _rate;

  // Amount of wei raised
  uint256 private _weiRaised;

  /**
   * Event for token purchase logging
   * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
   * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
   * @param value weis paid for purchase
   * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
   */
  event TokensPurchased(
    address indexed purchaser,
    address indexed beneficiary,
    uint256 value,
    uint256 amount
  );

  /**
   * @param rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
   * @dev The rate is the conversion between wei and the smallest and indivisible
   * token unit. So, if you are using a rate of 1 with a ERC20Detailed token
   * with 3 decimals called TOK, 1 wei will give you 1 unit, or 0.001 TOK.
   * @param wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
   * @param token Address of the token being sold
   */
  constructor(uint256 rate, address wallet, IERC20 token) internal {
    require(rate > 0);
    require(wallet != address(0));
    //require(token != address(0));
    require(address(token) != address(0));

    _rate = rate;
    _wallet = wallet;
    _token = token;
  }



  // -----------------------------------------
  // Crowdsale EXTERNAL interface
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev fallback function ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   * Note that other contracts will transfer fund with a base gas stipend
   * of 2300, which is not enough to call buyTokens. Consider calling
   * buyTokens directly when purchasing tokens from a contract.
   */
  function () external payable {
    buyTokens(msg.sender);
  }


  /**
   * @return the token being sold.
   */
  function token() public view returns(IERC20) {
    return _token;
  }


  /**
   * @return the address where funds are collected.
   */
  function wallet() public view returns(address) {
    return _wallet;
  }


  /**
   * @return the number of token units a buyer gets per wei.
   */
  function rate() public view returns(uint256) {
    return _rate;
  }


  /**
   * @return the amount of wei raised.
   */
  function weiRaised() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _weiRaised;
  }


  /**
   * @dev low level token purchase ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   * This function has a non-reentrancy guard, so it shouldn't be called by
   * another `nonReentrant` function.
   * @param beneficiary Recipient of the token purchase
   */
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public nonReentrant payable {
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    _preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);

    // update state
    _weiRaised = _weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    _processPurchase(beneficiary, tokens);

    emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

    _updatePurchasingState(beneficiary, weiAmount);

    _forwardFunds();
    _postValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);
  }


  // -----------------------------------------
  // INTERNALternal interface (extensible)
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to revert state when conditions are not met. Use `super` in contracts that inherit from Crowdsale to extend their validations.
   * Example from CappedCrowdsale.sol's _preValidatePurchase method:
   *   super._preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, weiAmount);
   *   require(weiRaised().add(weiAmount) <= cap);
   * @param beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
   // This function checks that the ADDRESS of the BENEFICIARY is not ZERO, and 
   // that the weiAmoun being purchased is also NOT ZERO:
  function _preValidatePurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) internal view {
    require(beneficiary != address(0));
    require(weiAmount != 0);
  }


  /**
   * @dev Validation of an executed purchase. Observe state and use revert statements to undo rollback when valid conditions are not met.
   * @param beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _postValidatePurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) internal view {
    // optional override
  }


  /**
   * @dev Source of tokens. Override this method to modify the way in which the crowdsale ultimately gets and sends its tokens.
   * @param beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param tokenAmount Number of tokens to be emitted
   */
  function _deliverTokens(address beneficiary, uint256 tokenAmount ) internal {
    _token.safeTransfer(beneficiary, tokenAmount);
  }



  /**
   * @dev Executed when a purchase has been validated and is ready to be executed. Doesn't necessarily emit/send tokens.
   * @param beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param tokenAmount Number of tokens to be purchased
   */
  function _processPurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 tokenAmount) internal {
    _deliverTokens(beneficiary, tokenAmount);
  }


  /**
   *  "_updatePurchasingState"
   * @dev Override for extensions that require an internal state to check for validity (current user contributions, etc.)
   * @param beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _updatePurchasingState(address beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) internal {
    // optional override
  }


  /**
   * @dev Override to extend the way in which ether is converted to tokens.
   * @param weiAmount Value in wei to be converted into tokens
   * @return Number of tokens that can be purchased with the specified _weiAmount
   */
  function _getTokenAmount(uint256 weiAmount) internal view returns (uint256) {
    return weiAmount.mul(_rate);
  }


  /**
   * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
   */
  function _forwardFunds() internal {
    _wallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

======================

UPDATE: here's the migration file

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

// ROPSTEN ENDPOINT:


    module.exports = {
        networks: {
            ropsten: {
                provider: function () {
                    return new HDWalletProvider(
                        process.env.MNENOMIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}"
                    )
                },
                network_id: 3,
                gas: 8000000
            },
            development: {
                host: "127.0.0.1",
                port: 8545,
                network_id: "*" // Match any network id
            },
        },
        solc: {
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most probably, any require condition is failing. Can you put custom error message in all require conditions like:  require(x==y, 'error X is not y')

Comment: ok, I added custom messages to all my `require` statements and I'm trying to redeploy the contract to `Ropsten` - and now I'm getting this lovely message: `Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value` .  I'm getting this message over and over again...

Comment: Either you're using too low gas limit or you are not properly synchronized with the network.

Comment: I'm not running my own Node, so I think that means it can't be a synchronization problem (right?)    In terms of the Gas, I've been looking it up here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/blocks  so I think I'm using good values.   I've update my original question to include my `truffle.js` file so you can see what I'm doing there.